# Compare filename with optional file extension

Tags: c, string

I need to check if a path stored in a string is actually a path to a file whose name I have stored in another string.

eg.: let's suppose I have a file at /etc/prog/myprog

I have this kind of function:

```
char *slash = strrchr(procname, '/');
if(slash && !strcmp(slash, name)){
    printf("FOUND!\n");
}
```

And it works fine when looking for "myprog", but it obviously doesn't work if the file has an extension (for example if strings ends with "/vim.basic" I want the if statement to be true when looking for "vim").

I guess I have to use strrchr to find the position of dot and if it exist, stop comparison at that char, but I have no idea how to construct the conditional statement to work this way.

Comment: And I know, I can use strstr, but I want the substring to be found specifically between a slash '/' and (if it exists) a dot '.'

Comment: Do you have more examples of both the inputs, comparisons and the expected output?

Comment: you can try strcmp

Comment: @TahTatsumoto I don't think the problem requires more examples. In short I am doing someting similar to pidof by reading symbolic links from /proc subfolders, so I want to find the process despite of the file having an extension, so "bash" would be true for "/bin/bash" but also "vim" would be true for "/usr/bin/vim.basic".

Comment: @Lashane you comment doesn't help at all, because I actually use strcmp... My problem is how to use it to achieve the effect I want.

Comment: @Nidrax I mean strNcmp, sorry for typo

Comment: @Lashane, oh, now it looks more promising. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes `strncmp` and some additional calculation and checks.

Note that your code is off by 1 at this point:

```
if (slash && !strcmp(slash, name))
```

.. `slash` will point *to the slash*, so unless you accounted for that in `name`, it will always fail.

This code works:

```
if (slash &&
    !strncmp(slash+1, name, strlen(name)) &&
    (!slash[1+strlen(name)] || slash[1+strlen(name)] == '.'))
{
    printf("FOUND!\n");
}
```

It checks if the first *n* characters at `slash+1` are equal to `name` with the *length* of `name` – thus, it checks the `vim` in `etc/vim.basic` – and then checks if `name` is immediately followed by a `0` end-of string *or* by a `.` character.

It's slightly easier on the eyes if you can modify `procname`:

```
if (slash)
{
    char *dot = strchr (slash, '.');
    if (dot) *dot = 0;
    if (!strcmp(slash+1, name))
    {
        printf("FOUND!\n");
    }
}
```

(Will not work if `procname` cannot be changed, as in `char *procname = ".."`. OTOH if it can, you could even restore the original string by adding

```
if (dot) *dot = '.';
```

at the end.)